# How to enable search button in HTML help Workshop software

Tags: html, search, tabs

I have installed HTML help Workshop software (version 4.73) in my system and I have created a project.I could open the .chm file and view the files under it. However, I am not getting the search tab in .chm file. I am getting **stop** menu item in "OPTIONS" menu.

How can I display search tab in .chm file?

Comment: Just to add some comments on an old question while looking a similar problem: I've found some mentions of a problem with the registration (with regsvr32) of the ITCC.DLL, so registering again this dll may help; on my side, I have a clue that my (still not solved) problem is related to an interaction with the antivirus, which locks a temporary file, failing a CreateFileMapping call...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML Help workshop 4.74, you can double click the options section in the Project tab. Then, a dialog opens. In the dialog, enable the Compiler tab page, and thenre, check the "Compile full-text search" option. If you then compile, you get a search functionality in your .chm file.